# Beginning Python, Conditional Testing With or Statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements, or-operator

```
number_1=18
number_2=20
print(number_1>=20) or (number_2>=20)
```

Output: False

I was writing some code for conditional testing in python, and I was very confused on why `(number_1>=20) or (number_2>=20)`  had an output of False.

I know that the or statement has to have at least one of its expressions evaluate to True in order to have an output of True. To support this, the variable number_2=20, so 20>=20 should equal True and therefore making the output True. I was puzzled to see that the output was False. I fiddled around with the code for a while until I had this piece of code, almost identical to the previous one, and it worked surprisingly.

`print(number_1>=20 or number_2>=20)`

I am struggling to find why this code above me works and the previous code does not work.

Thank you so much for the support!

Comment: You are only printing one thing `print(number_1>=20)` Maybe you wanted: `print(number_1>=20 or number_2>=20)`?

Comment: Oh ok, that makes much more sense, I didn't realize that the print() statement didn't reach or (number_2>=20), rendering the code to false, thank you so much!

Comment: Oh it reached the number_2>=20, but it wasn't until after the `print` had finished.  It calculated a result that was then ignored since you didn't print or assign it.

Comment: So, the print statement only executed number_1>=20 and then it finished the rest of the calculation (number_2>=20) without showing the result due to the print() statement not being assigned to that specific peice of code.

Comment: `print()` only prints its arguments. Why would you expect it to do anything with what comes after it?